# angular ng-repeat filter by number

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I'm having some trouble filtering an list by type (number) in angular (1.5.8)

my ng repeat with filter is as following:

```
ng-repeat="activity in guild.history_updates | filter : {
    action_type: filters.action_type,
    user_id: filters.user,
}"
```

and my filter

```
<md-input-container class="md-block">
    <label>Type</label>
    <md-select ng-model="filters.action_type">
        <md-option>
            All
        </md-option>
        <md-option ng-repeat="action_type in guildActivityCtrl.action_types"
            ng-value="action_type.type">
            {{action_type.name}} ({{ action_type.type }})
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

When I'm filtering on action_type 1 I'm also getting action types 10

[image: filter action type 1]
[image: filter action type 1 result]

But when I chage the filter to 10, I'm getting the right results

[image: filter action type 10]
[image: filter action type 10 result]

Every other action type is filtered good as well (e.g. action_type 3)

[image: filter action type 3]
[image: filter action type 3 result]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ng-repeat="activity in guild.history_updates | filter:{action_type:filters.action_type,user_id: filters.user}:true"
```

Adding ":true" after your filter should change this to a strict equality check, now comparing the numeric values.

Hope this helps.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

The Arguments section defines the comparator.

Comment: adding `:true` will show zero results on every filter

Comment: Is that because it's failing on the action_type:filters.  I would be interested to know what simply filtering user_id would give you.  I'm guessing that the strict check on action_type is why you're not getting anything back.

Comment: using `:true` won't have any effect on the user filter indeed, only the action type filter won't show up with any results

Comment: user_id: filters.user, should this be user_id: filters.user_id?  Sorry, I guess I might not be understanding your problem.  Just trying to help.

Comment: filters.user will give and user id, sorry for the confusion. the problem is when filtering on action_type = 1 I'm also getting results where the action_type is 10

Comment: Thanks, this brought me to an idea! I don't want the user to fill in the action_type number themselfs but I can parse the action_type to an number and filter on that.

Answer (score 1):

Like Neal Hamilton said, we need to add `:true` to add a strict equality check.

Adding `:true` won't work when the output of the md-select isn't a number so we can add a filter to parse the output to a number like:

```
.filter('parseInt', function() {
    return function(number) {
        if(!number) {
            return false;
        }
        return parseInt(number , 10);
    };
})
```

We can add this filter to the ng-repeats' filter like:

```
ng-repeat="activity in guild.history_updates | filter : {
    action_type: (filters.action_type | parseInt ),
    user_id: filters.user,
} : true"
```

Edit: When you don't want to strict check every value in the filters you can use multiple filters like:

```
ng-repeat="activity in guild.history_updates
| filter : {
    action_type: (filters.action_type | parseInt ),

} : true
| filter: {
    user_id: filters.user
}"
```